# Unexpected Integer Change (Memory Overflow)

Tags: c

I am trying to concatenate two strings in C in a for loop and run into a problem where my integer (i) suddenly becomes a seemingly random number after it gets read once.

```
char string[] = "Example String";
char result[] = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", i); //i prints 0 on the first loop and a random
                       //number the next, which terminates the program.
    strcat(result, string);
    printf("%s\n", result);
}
```

Comment: What integer ??

Comment: How `stackTrace` is defined? Are you sure it is big enough, and writing to it doesn't overflow and change some other memory, maybe allocated for `i`?

Comment: And how does `stack` get filled?

Comment: It looks like you're incrementing a pointer to this integer rather than the integer itself. The value 1886352492 is 706f746c in hex, which reads as `"ltop"` in ASCII (assuming big-endian). Does that correspond to the start (or end) of a character string in the same stack frame?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage How am I doing this? I am trying to take what's assigned at place "i" from an array.

Comment: It looks like you're overwriting `i` when you write to `stackTrace` because it's on the stack.  Try allocating space properly for `stackTrace`.

Comment: @e0k This is the problem, thanks. I was just being dumb and forgot how that's gonna be an obvious problem. It works fine now.

Comment: The size of your `stackTrace` array is one byte (`'\0'`), but you're writing much more than that to it.

Comment: `stackTrace` is an array of char of length `1` placed on your stack. You cannot possibly use it to write anything other than an empty null-terminated string.

Comment: @a3ology: don't just assume you have enough space if it "works fine" right now. Create the program so that the buffer cannot overflow when you concatenate the string.

Comment: I also suggest looking at `snprintf()` to help you manage your `stackTrace` allocation properly.

Comment: @Groo I meant I fixed the problem by allocating enough space, sorry for not clarifying that. I was just forgetting basic stuff because I took a break and came back..

Comment: @a3ology I think what Groo means to say is that you should dynamically compute what the string's length is going to be, at runtime, and then allocate the buffer accordingly. Don't just allocate a large amount of space and say, eh, it'll probably never be longer than that. Remember Murphy's Law: if it _can_ go wrong, it _will_.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Fine, I'll stop being lazy... I was just going to give it (the maximum length of a directory + the length of the following ASCII code) * the amount of lines, which would always work, but it would be nicer to have it done correctly.

Comment: @a3ology: yes, even if you don't want to dynamically allocate, make sure you are keeping count of the remaining length while concatenating using [some safe method](https://www.sudo.ws/todd/papers/strlcpy.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're initializing a string of length 1, including the null terminator.

```
char result[] = "";
```

So when you try to write `string` to `result`, and the string is longer than result (as is likely, as `sizeof result` is 1), you're overflowing it, which is an undefined behavior:

```
strcat(result /* length of 1*/ , string /* length of 15*/);
```

If you convert the random number you see stored in `i` to hex, and use its ASCII values, you may see parts of string you are writing. This is because, if your string is long enough, you cause a... Stack Overflow. (ba dum chshhhhhh)

And thus other random memory is getting overwritten by your string, including the memory where `i` is stored.

SOLUTION: Allocate the `result` variable as a pointer with enough memory to store the string you need to put in it. In this case:

```
char string[] = "Example String";
char * result = malloc(sizeof (char*) + (sizeof string * 10)); // 10 being the number of iterations in the for loop
```

Keep in mind you can also use something like `result = realloc(result, sizeof(char *) + previousResultSize + concatStringLength);` if you need to change how much memory is allocated. Just don't forget about your null terminator with strings!

Comment: `sprintf(stackTrace, "%s%s\n", stackTrace, stack[i]);` is still undefined behavior, even if `stackTrace` is a large array.

Comment: Here is the Wikipedia page of [C Dynamic Memory Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), which is the solution to this problem. Read up on when to use dynamic memory allocation and how to do so. This is an essential concept in C programming, which is handled automatically in many high-level languages.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the local stack memory with your call to `sprintf()` - this is what is causing this UB (undefined behavior). And you can clearly see why this is called a UB: you cannot reliably tell "what will happen" before you run the program :)

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behavior.

> `sprintf()`
>   If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined. C11 §7.21.6.6 2

```
//      v--------v   and      v--------v overlap  
sprintf(stackTrace, "%s%s\n", stackTrace, stack[i]); // UB
```

`char stackTrace[] = "";` is too small [@Charles Srstka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49927466/2410359).  Declaring `stackTrace[]`  with memory like `char stackTrace[1000] = "";` is **not** sufficient.  Code needs to append in a specified manner.

---

Instead declare a buffer and append to it by keeping track of the end of the string used so far.

```
char **stack;
char stackTrace[10000];
stackTrace[0] = '\0';
char *st = stackTrace;

for (int i = 0; i < levels /*500*/; i++) {
  printf("debug %i\n", i);

  // In some fashion, perform a safe concatenation
  size_t remaining_size = &stackTrace[sizeof stackTrace] - st;
  sprintf(st, remaining_size, "%s\n", stack[i]);
  // update `st` to the end of the string
  st += strlen(st);

  printf(stackTrace);  // do not use stackTrace as a _format_
  printf("%s", stackTrace);
}
```

For the purposes of a *stack trace*, it is a good idea [@YePhIcK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1482455/yephick) to allocate the stack trace buffer early in a program run - perhaps as a `static`.

```
// char stackTrace[10000];
static char stackTrace[10000];
```

---

For the purpose of a *stack trace*, using a safe append is critical as the need for a *stack trace* often implies something may be amiss. `snprintf()` is complex function.  Using non-standard functions like `strlcpy()/strlcat()` [@Groo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927288/unexpected-integer-change-in-for-loop/49929706#comment86871421_49927288) or equivalent is a good idea.